# UWP how to upload a list of images from different folders to different pivotItems

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm creating an UWP App image gallery and I want to upload a list of images
with a single method changing folder location to multipes PivotItems with a single method

```
  public async void precargar()
    {
          List<StackPanel> spanel = new List<StackPanel>();
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await Imagefolder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
            StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = null;
            try { thumbnail = await item.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView); }

            catch (Exception) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("esto es un error lo sentimos"); }

            BitmapImage bi;
            if (thumbnail == null)
            {
                bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///wallpaper/2.png"));
            }
            else
            {
                Stream stream = thumbnail.AsStream();
                bi = new BitmapImage();
                await bi.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            }

            Image image = new Image() { Width = 300 };
            image.Source = bi;
            stack.Children.Add(image);
            spanel.Add(stack);
        }
       Viewtiles.ItemsSource = spanel;
    }
```

the above code works correctly
in this way:
and I use it in this way to load them to the interface

```
public async void CargarFolders()
    {
        Imagefolder = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync(carpetas[0]);
        precargar();

    }
```

Now I want to use that code to load other lists of images using the same code in the following way:

```
public async void Naturaleza()
    {
        Imagefolder = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync(carpetas[1]);
        precargar();
        Naturals.ItemsSource = spanel;
    }
```

but it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: I checked your code, but I actually did not know what you have done.So, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Besides, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use FlipView control rather than pivot control for displaying image. Because FlipView control has move forward and backward option with touch friendly. You can set large sets of images to FlipView control.

Please go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/flipview